# How to put attribute from list object from one into second action

Tags: jsp, struts2

I think that my question is pretty easy but i am trying since one week to get that work.

I have a `MainAction` which has a list of `Processes` like this:

```
private List<Process> processes;
```

with getter and setter

to edit or delete a process I have a processForm.jsp and a `ProcessAction`.

So my problem is to get the id of a special process from the list into the `ProcessAction`.

when i tried this:

```
<s:hidden name="processes[%{#status.index}].id"/>
```

the id is inside the hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="processes[0].id" value="20" id="ShowMain_processes_0__id">
```

but not mapped to the action

when i try it like this:

```
<s:hidden name="process.id" value="processes[%{#status.index}].id"/>
```

it doesn't work at all....

so can someone help me how to do ?

Here the new details:

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">

<struts>
<package name="default" extends="tiles-default">

    <action name="ShowMain" class="com.goemon.smart.action.MainAction">
        <result type="tiles">mainForm</result>
    </action>

    <action name="Cancel" class="com.goemon.smart.action.MainAction">
        <result type="redirectAction">ShowMain</result>
    </action>

    <action name="ExecuteStartAction" class="com.goemon.smart.action.MainAction" method="executeStartCommand">
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">ShowMain</result>
        <result name="input" type="redirectAction">ShowMain</result>
    </action>

    <action name="ExecuteStopAction" class="com.goemon.smart.action.MainAction" method="executeStopCommand">
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">ShowMain</result>
        <result name="input" type="redirectAction">ShowMain</result>
    </action>

    <action name="DeleteProcess" class="com.goemon.smart.action.MainAction" method="deleteProcess">
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">ShowMain</result>
    </action>

    <action name="ShowAction" class="com.goemon.smart.action.ProcessAction">
        <result type="tiles">actionForm</result>
    </action>

    <action name="CreateAction" class="com.goemon.smart.action.ProcessAction" method="createAction">
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">ShowMain</result>
        <result name="error" type="redirectAction">ShowAction</result>
        <result name="input" type="redirectAction">ShowAction</result>
    </action>

    <action name="EditCommandAction" class="com.goemon.smart.action.ProcessAction" method="editAction">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">actionForm</result>
    </action>

    <action name="InsertDefault" class="com.goemon.smart.action.ProcessAction" method="insertDefaults">
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">ShowMain</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

mainForm.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>

<div class="container">
<legend>
    <h1><s:text name="header.mainpage"/></h1>
</legend>

<s:iterator var="currentProcess" value="processes">
    <div class="jumbotron well col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1">
        <s:form theme="bootstrap" cssClass="bs-example form-horizontal">

            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
                <s:a action="DeleteProcess">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </s:a>
                <s:a action="EditCommandAction">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </s:a>
            </div>

            <s:hidden name="id" value="%{#currentProcess.id}"/>

            <h2>
                <s:text name="%{#currentProcess.name}"/>
            </h2>

            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
                <s:submit key="btn.start" action="ExecuteStartAction"
                          cssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-success"/>
                <s:submit key="btn.stop" action="ExecuteStopAction"
                          cssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-danger"/>
            </div>
        </s:form>
    </div>
</s:iterator>
<s:debug/>
```

processForm.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 well">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <s:form theme="bootstrap" cssClass="bs-example form-horizontal">

        <legend>
            <s:text name="header.manage"/>
        </legend>

        <s:hidden name="initial"/>
        <s:textfield name="process.name" key="lbl.process.name" cssClass="col-lg-12"/>
        <s:textfield name="process.host" key="lbl.process.host" cssClass="col-lg-12"/>

        <div class="col-lg-11 pull-right">
            <s:iterator var="counter" begin="0" end="2">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <s:hidden name="process.commands[%{#counter}].id"/>

                    <s:select key="lbl.command.type" list="commandTypeValues"
                              name="process.commands[%{#counter}].commandType" headerKey=""
                              headerValue="%{commandTypeValues[#counter]}"/>

                    <s:textfield name="process.commands[%{#counter}].command"
                                 key="lbl.process.command"/>
                </div>
            </s:iterator>
        </div>

        <s:textfield name="process.user" key="lbl.process.user" cssClass="col-lg-12"/>
        <s:textfield name="process.password" key="lbl.process.password" cssClass="col-lg-12"/>

        <s:submit key="btn.create" action="CreateAction" cssClass="btn btn-primary pull-right"/>
        <s:submit key="btn.cancel" action="Cancel" cssClass="btn btn-primary pull-right"/>

        <s:debug />
    </s:form>
</div>
```

ProcessAction.java

```
package com.goemon.smart.action;

import com.goemon.smart.model.CommandType;
import com.goemon.smart.model.Process;
import com.goemon.smart.service.ProcessService;
import com.goemon.smart.util.DefaultingUtil;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Preparable;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

/**
 * Created by John on 4/4/15.
 */
public class ProcessAction extends ActionSupport implements Preparable {

@Autowired
private ProcessService processService;

@Autowired
private DefaultingUtil defaultingUtil;

private Process process;

private Long id;

private CommandType[] commandTypeValues = CommandType.values();

@Override
public void prepare() throws Exception {
}

public String execute() {
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String createAction() {
    try {
        processService.saveAction(process);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return INPUT;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String editAction() {
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String insertDefaults() {
    try {
        Process ambiLight = defaultingUtil.ambiLightDefault();
        processService.saveAction(ambiLight);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}

public Process getProcess() {
    return process;
}

public void setProcess(Process process) {
    this.process = process;
}

public CommandType[] getCommandTypeValues() {
    return commandTypeValues;
}

public void setCommandTypeValues(CommandType[] commandTypeValues) {
    this.commandTypeValues = commandTypeValues;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

Comment: Post `struts.xml` where the actual mappings are.

Comment: Do you want to iterate on the list or just want the first element on list??

Comment: I have a main page where i display all processes of the list and each element has a delete and a edit button so that is the reason why i need the id

Comment: So you think that pressing on link with button inside (yuck) will submit your form? Remove buttons from links use css to style them and use `<s:param>` to pass id.

Comment: can you explain it a little bit more... I added `<s:param name="id" value="%{#currentProcess.id}"/>` to the mainForm.jsp but still no id in the ProcessAction.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the status object to access fields while iterating. Struts puts the current list item on the top of the value stack, so this will suffice:

```
<s:hidden name="process.id" value="%{id}"/>
```

Alternatively you can specify a variable name in the iterator tag:

```
<s:iterator var="currentProcess" value="processes">
    <s:hidden name="process.id" value="%{#currentProcess.id}"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Note that the `name` attribute must match a field in your `ProcessAction`. So in case of `name="process.id"` you need a field `process`, must likely  of the type `Process`, which must be initialized, before Struts inserts the value or you will get a NullpointerException.

If you use `<s:hidden/>`, make sure to use `<s:submit>` tags like you did for "ExecuteStartAction" instead of `<button>`.

If you want to use links instead of form buttons, use this:

```
<s:url var="editUrl" action="EditCommandAction">
    <s:param name="id" value="%{#currentProcess.id}" />
</s:url>
<s:a href="%{editUrl}">...</s:a>
```

You can then use CSS to style the link however you want.

But as Alexandr M already said, don't mix buttons and links.

Comment: thanks Stefan looks good but where do i have to initialize the process ? i tried it in several way but didn't get the id in it :/

Comment: Actually I would suggest using a simple field `id` in `ProcessAction` for the call to the Edit/Delete dialog instead. Use the field `process` for the dialog only. The separation should make the code cleaner and easier to understand and you won't get inconsistent data in `process`.

Comment: ok... I tried it with `<s:hidden name="id" value="%{#currentProcess.id}"/>` and the `id value` is right in html page but in edit case the `id` in the `ProcessAction` is still null :( `id' field in `ProcessAction` is the same as in `Process` and has getter and setter

Comment: Strange. Can you post the jsp code for the complete form then? And the action mapping as Roman suggested?

Comment: I enhanced the answer by what Alexandr said basically. One thing is still unclear to me though. Did you omit code in `ProcessAction`? Because I couldn't find where the selected data set is loaded into the `process` field.

Comment: so i just need the `<s:param>` in the jsp? or do i need to change my struts config as well ?